# laravel ajax action url with parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem with an ajax call. The url that i need to get the data is:

```
localhost/public/getCode?course_id=1&task_id=1
```

My ajax call is:

```
function getCode() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: "{{action('CodeEditorController@getCode',['course_id'=>$course,'task_id'=>$maintask])}}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }
```

But the data returned is empty.

Edit:
getCode function:

```
public function getCode(Request $request)
{
    $code=Code::where('user_id',$user->id)->where('main_task_id',$request->input('task_id'))->first()->code;
    $response = [
        'data' => $code
    ];

    return response()->json($response, 200);
}
```

What is the issue with my ajax code?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code in your getCode method?

Comment: Any errors returned or just empty result set? Try adding error logging for ajax request after your success statement. `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   $content.fadeOut(200);
   console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
         console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);`

Comment: @AndrewNolan no error, just empty response. With postman it returns the data, but with my ajax call it wont. I think its a problem with my ajax code

Comment: hmmm, maybe try adding your parameters as a data section in ajax call instead of attached to url. `data: {'task_id' : $maintask, 'course_id' : $course}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do that is to use `data` for options:

```
data: {
    'course_id': {{ $course }},
    'task_id': {{ $maintask }} 
},
```

To get values in controller you can just use `request('course_id')` and `request('task_id')`

Also it's a really bad idea to use Blade/PHP to build JS. You should use hidden inputs or something to pass data to JS.